# Jquery Table Sum

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create rows every time I click the "+" button and sum every column. I can create columns.
But no rows.

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tabla").click(function () {
        $("tr").find("td:last").before('<td><input type="text" value="0"></td>');
        $("tr:last").after('<td><input type="text" value="1"></td>');
        $("input").each(function () {
            $(this).keyup(function () {
                newSum.call(this);

            });
        });
    });
});


function newSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr');

    var total = 0;

    $(thisRow).find("td:not(.total) input").each(function () {

        sum += parseInt(this.value);
    });
    $(thisRow).find(".total").html(sum);

    $('.total').each(function () {

        total += parseInt($(this).html());
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YQ7LQ/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you remember to include JQuery? (You didn't in your fiddle...)

Also: `$("tr").find("td:last")` fins the last column of each row, and then you add another cell before it, creating a new column. You never really asked it to create a new row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved the problem.

Here's the code:

```
    //Sum the Rows.
    $('#sum_table tr:not(.totalCol) input:text').bind('keyup change', function() {
    var $table = $(this).closest('table');
    var total = 0;
    var thisNumber = $(this).attr('class').match(/(\d+)/)[1];

    $table.find('tr:not(.totalCol) .sum'+thisNumber).each(function() {
        total += parseInt(this.value);
    });

    $table.find('.totalCol td:nth-child('+thisNumber+')').html(total);
});
```

Here is the full code:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/NVByC/)

Answer (score 0):

Added rows and columns sum called on `$(document).on('keyup','input',newSum);` 
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/a6P32/1/)

Comment: Thank you dude!, One question. If I want to make the column result increment too like the row is it possible?

Comment: @devtreat What do you mean?

Comment: If you see my fiddle, When I click "+" Button,my column and rows increment, I want to sum column but when I click "+", I got more total to sum again like the rows.

Comment: @devtreat ok,so with the click on + you want to increase columns and rows. Right

Comment: Yes and sum the columns like we do with the rows